# creating a dashboard using ajax and XML

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, web-applications

I need a little help in this, I am trying to build a dashboard using Ajax which parses the data from an XML file and displays it on the table/dashboard. I want something like, if there is a change in the data of XML, it should reflect it on the website too (live)/without the page being reloaded. I tried several tips related to setInterval() function but it just duplicates the whole result and keeps on doing that.. below is the ajax script and xml from which I am trying to do that. File name of XMl is XMLFile.xml. the little content of my Xml is in the comment.. suppose if there is the change in the first attribute say, DNSStatus changes from 'OK' to 'NOTOK', the green tick should change to red cross, live and that too without refreshing the whole page.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   var CheckImage = "<img src= 'images/check.png' height=''20 width='20'>";
    var CrossImage = "<img src= 'images/cross.png' height=''20 width='20'>";

       $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'XMLFile.xml',
            dataType: 'xml',
            cache: false,
            success: function (xml) {

                $(xml).find("URLs").each(function ()
                {
                    var Sitename = $(this).find('ProdURL').attr('ProdHost')
                    var URLType = $(this).find('ProdURL').attr('URLType')
                    var DNSStatus = $(this).find('ProdURL').attr('DNSStatus')
                    var TargetStatus = $(this).find('ProdURL').attr('TargetStatus')
                    var TTL = $(this).find('ProdURL').attr('TTL')
                    var SSL = $(this).find('ProdURL').attr('SSL')
                    var Force = $(this).find('ProdURL').attr('Force')

                    showData(Sitename, URLType, DNSStatus, TargetStatus, TTL, SSL, Force);

                });

                $(xml).find("URLs").each(function () {
                    var Sitename = $(this).find('RootURL').attr('RootHost')
                    var URLType = $(this).find('RootURL').attr('URLType')
                    var DNSStatus = $(this).find('RootURL').attr('DNSStatus')
                    var TargetStatus = $(this).find('RootURL').attr('TargetStatus')
                    var TTL = $(this).find('RootURL').attr('TTL')
                    var SSL = $(this).find('RootURL').attr('SSL')
                    var Force = $(this).find('RootURL').attr('Force')
                    showData(Sitename, URLType, DNSStatus, TargetStatus, TTL, SSL, Force);

                });

                $(xml).find("URLs").each(function () {
                    var Sitename = $(this).find('WorkingURL').attr('WorkingHost')
                    var URLType = $(this).find('WorkingURL').attr('URLType')
                    var DNSStatus = $(this).find('WorkingURL').attr('DNSStatus')
                    var TargetStatus = $(this).find('WorkingURL').attr('TargetStatus')
                    var TTL = $(this).find('WorkingURL').attr('TTL')
                    var SSL = $(this).find('WorkingURL').attr('SSL')
                    var Force = $(this).find('WorkingURL').attr('Force')
                    showData(Sitename, URLType, DNSStatus, TargetStatus, TTL, SSL, Force);

                });

                $(xml).find("URLs").each(function () {
                    var Sitename = $(this).find('ModuleURL').attr('ModuleHost')
                    var URLType = $(this).find('ModuleURL').attr('URLType')
                    var DNSStatus = $(this).find('ModuleURL').attr('DNSStatus')
                    var TargetStatus = $(this).find('ModuleURL').attr('TargetStatus')
                    var TTL = $(this).find('ModuleURL').attr('TTL')
                    var SSL = $(this).find('ModuleURL').attr('SSL')
                    var Force = $(this).find('ModuleURL').attr('Force')
                    showData(Sitename, URLType, DNSStatus, TargetStatus, TTL, SSL, Force);

                });

                $(xml).find("URLs").each(function () {
                    var Sitename = $(this).find('Moduleurl').attr('ModuleHost')
                    var URLType = $(this).find('Moduleurl').attr('URLType')
                    var DNSStatus = $(this).find('Moduleurl').attr('DNSStatus')
                    var TargetStatus = $(this).find('Moduleurl').attr('TargetStatus')
                    var TTL = $(this).find('Moduleurl').attr('TTL')
                    var SSL = $(this).find('Moduleurl').attr('SSL')
                    var Force = $(this).find('Moduleurl').attr('Force')
                    showData(Sitename, URLType, DNSStatus, TargetStatus, TTL, SSL, Force);

                });

                $(xml).find("URLs").each(function () {
                    var Sitename = $(this).find('VanityURL').attr('VanityHost')
                    var URLType = $(this).find('VanityURL').attr('URLType')
                    var DNSStatus = $(this).find('VanityURL').attr('DNSStatus')
                    var TargetStatus = $(this).find('VanityURL').attr('TargetStatus')
                    var TTL = $(this).find('VanityURL').attr('TTL')
                    var SSL = $(this).find('VanityURL').attr('SSL')
                    var Force = $(this).find('VanityURL').attr('Force')
                    showData(Sitename, URLType, DNSStatus, TargetStatus, TTL, SSL, Force);

                });

                $(xml).find("URLs").each(function () {
                    var Sitename = $(this).find('Vanityurl').attr('VanityHost')
                    var URLType = $(this).find('Vanityurl').attr('URLType')
                    var DNSStatus = $(this).find('Vanityurl').attr('DNSStatus')
                    var TargetStatus = $(this).find('Vanityurl').attr('TargetStatus')
                    var TTL = $(this).find('Vanityurl').attr('TTL')
                    var SSL = $(this).find('Vanityurl').attr('SSL')
                    var Force = $(this).find('Vanityurl').attr('Force')
                    showData(Sitename, URLType, DNSStatus, TargetStatus, TTL, SSL, Force);

                });

            }


        });


    function showData(Sitename, URLType, DNSStatus, TargetStatus, TTL, SSL, Force)
    {
        var TargetStatusImage;
        if (TargetStatus === "OK")
        {
            TargetStatusImage = CheckImage;
        }
        else
        {
            TargetStatusImage = CrossImage;
        }
        var DNSStatusImage;
        if (DNSStatus === "OK")
        {
            DNSStatusImage = CheckImage;
        }
        else
        {
            DNSStatusImage = CrossImage;
        }
        var SSLImage;
        if (SSL === "OK")
        {
            SSLImage = CheckImage;
        }
        else
        {
            SSLImage = CrossImage;
        }
        $('#demo tbody').append('<tr><td>' + Sitename + '</td><td>' + URLType + '</td><td>' + DNSStatusImage + '</td><td>' + TargetStatusImage + '</td><td>' + TTL + '</td><td>' + SSLImage + '</td><td>' + Force + '</td></tr>')

    }

</script>
```

Input file example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<!--Website Status--> 
<WebApplication> 
  <URLs> 
    <ProdURL ProdHost="www.wellington.ca" URLType="Prod" DNSStatus="OK" TargetStatus="OK" TTL="300" SSL="OK" Force="Yes" /> 
    <RootURL RootHost="wellington.ca" URLType="Root" DNSStatus="OK" TargetStatus="NotOK" TTL="3583" SSL="OK" Force="Yes" />
    <ModuleURL ModuleHost="calendar.wellington.ca" URLType="Module" DNSStatus="OK" TargetStatus="OK" TTL="297" SSL="OK" Force="Yes" /> 
  </URLs>
</WebApplication>
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: @Machavity can you help me with one thing with my web page code? I am trying to add a column in the table which would show a time stamp when the data in the XML is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `append` when setting data `$('#demo tbody').append()` you need to overwrite existing values. try using `$('#demo tbody').html(<your data goes here>)`.

Comment: It worked but it only showed me one of the content.. the other content were not displayed..

Comment: Then you need to modify your `ShowData()` code to cleanup existing info on first call and append on subsequent calls in the same callback

Comment: With append, it would display the whole table content.. with html, it showed only the last content of xml

Comment: Add one more argument to `ShowData()` and if that argument is `true` then use `html` if `false` use `append`. And pass `true` when you show for `ProdURL` and pass `false` in all other cases

Comment: can you please modify the code and paste it in the comment??

Comment: I want all the results to be displayed at same time..and site should monitor the changes...